# Creating a YouTube Video or Channel ID validation in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am learning how to use the YouTube Data API through Apps Script.  I am now trying to modify the example provided here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/apps-script to verify if the ID exists.

I slightly modified it to look at video IDs since that is more common.

With help by @Tanaike based on my last question, Tanaike helped me create a loop to allow the script to add IDs as comma-separated.  Now I'm trying to add a validation.

```
function channelsListByVideoid(part,params){
  var response = YouTube.Videos.list(part,params);
  var video = response.items[0];
  var dataRow = [video.id,video.status.uploadStatus, video.snippet.title, response.pageInfo.totalResults, video.snippet.channelId, video.snippet.channelTitle];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName().appendRow(dataRow);

function getvideo() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var videoId = ui.prompt("Enter the YouTube Video ID: ").getResponseText();
  var values = videoId.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  channelsListByVideoid('snippet,status,contentDetails,statistics', {'id': values[i].trim()});
```

Sometimes, a video ID such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--fPZOu_H8g is not available.  Running that ID within the apps-script example will throw an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` which will stop the script from running.

I was thinking about how to use video.list.response Property:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    video Resource
  ]
}
```

The totalResults and the resultsPerPage will show as 1 if the video is valid and 0 if invalid:

```
"pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
```

which can be verified through the API explorer (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22--fPZOu_H8g%22%7D)

I added ````
response.pageInfo.totalResults,

`````
Logically to me, I need to add a 
````var response```` 
to my getvideo() and add the validation check within the loop.

I'm not clear if you can write it as simply as
`````

if response.pageinfo.totalResults = 1 then "valid" ELSE "Invalid"

```
and then how to allow the code to skip the error that is generated.

Thank you!
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation. And from your reply comment, I cannot replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So now I remove my answer. When I could correctly understand about your goal. I would like to update my answer.

Comment: I think the error is coming from the ID doesn't have a Title.  I'm not sure if I need to put a check ID function in the loop or in my Videoid function to skip/ignore. 

`function channelsListByVideoid(part,params){
  var response = YouTube.Videos.list(part,params);
//  if (response.items.length > 0);

  var video = response.items[0];
  if (response.pageInfo.totalResults > 0) {
  var dataRow = [video.id,video.status.uploadStatus, video.snippet.title, video.status.uploadStatus, video.snippet.channelId, video.snippet.channelTitle];
  } 
  else //need to add the check here
`

Comment: @Tanaike you have been more than helpful.  If it's easier I can share with you the script but you are still understand this language more than I do.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon. I cannot understand about your current situation yet. This is due to my poor skill. When I could correctly understand about your issue, I would like to think of the solution. But now, I have to apologize for this situation.

Comment: @stirfryguy the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` might indicate the object is undefined before trying read the `id` property. Please [edit] your question with two response examples: one response with a `videoId` working as expected *(I assume you have at least one `videoId`)* and other response from the `videoId` **--fPZOu_H8g** - this is due I don't know about google app scripts, but I'm 50% sure your problem relies on the response. You're assuming always the response will have the `id` key/value.